# Jade - missing space before text for line x of jade file

Tags: pug

I'm making an Express based web application and everytime someone visits this jade file i get the following error:

```
Warning: missing space before text for line 28 of jade file "C:\x\app\view
s\login.jade"
```

It also spits it out a few times for each line it happens on.

I took a look at these lines and I can not figure out what it's complaining about.

My jade file is as follows:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        link(href='style.css', rel='stylesheet')
    body
        .wrapper
            header.header
                a(href="/", style="color: #000000;")
                    h1(style="position: absolute; top: 30px;") Hello
            .middle
                .container
                    main.stream
                        p Login
                    main.name
                        form(id="login",    method="POST", action="/login")
                            table(cellspacing="15")
                                tr
                                    td Email
                                    td
                                        input(type='email', name='email' style="width: 250; height: 18px; border: 1px solid #999999; padding: 5px;")
                                tr
                                    td Password
                                    td
                                        input(type='password', name='password' style="width: 250; height: 18px; border: 1px solid #999999; padding: 5px;")
                                tr
                                    td
                                        input(style="width:75px;height:30px;", type="submit", value="Login")    

                aside.left-sidebar
                    main.dir
                        a(href="/") Home
                    main.dir
                        a(href="/signup")   Register                        
        footer.footer
            h3 Hello
            p This is a footer
```

Comment: I don't think it's a big deal, but you use a mix of commas and no commas in your element syntax.

`input(type='password', name='password' style="width: 250; height: 18px; border: 1px solid #999999; padding: 5px;")`

vs

`input(style="width:75px;height:30px;", type="submit", value="Login")`

Comment: @WaynePincence Indeed, I have no idea how I didn't catch that, thanks!

Answer (score 46):

In Jade use | when start with only text

wrong ->

```
td
  {{anything}}
  br
  Hello
```

correct ->

```
td
  | {{anything}}
  br
  | Hello
```

Comment: **One thing to add:** If you have a block of script starting with `script.` then the reported line for the problem will be wrong: all lines of such script are not counted!

Comment: Thanks for that @ishahak!  I had a feeling the line numbers were not matching up, as it was giving me this error on a blank line.  A bit of careful counting led me to the problem.

Answer (score 24):

I got this error when using the !{} syntax and had an extra return:

```
.row 
  !{marked(val)}
```

should be:

```
.row !{marked(val)}
```

Comment: Yes, I also had this error with a script tag containing only one line of javascript indented afterwards. Seems you have to put it on the same line. Thanks - your tip solved it for me.

Answer (score 11):

Why this problem occurs even when all of your jade *seems* valid is highlighted in this [github issue](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1591).
Quoting from the original issue itself:

> The warning is because `!{}` and `#{}` are for interpolation within text. i.e. you have to be **in(side) a text (block)** to start with. You should use `=` and `!=` to buffer JavaScript expressions.

This means that the `!{}` and `#{}` are only to be used if you are interpolating within an existing text-block. Something like coffee-script's `#{}` interpolation here:

```
a = "Hi #{name}!"
```

translates to (in javascript)

```
a = "Hi " + name + "!";
```

Thus, in Jade too, you'll use the `!{}` and `!{}` within a running text (a paragraph or a string). To just output a string from a variable without explicitly starting a new text-block, you'd use `=` or `!=`.

```
.row
  != marked(val)
.another-row
  = marked(val)
```

An alternative would be to *explicitly* start a new text-block as so:

```
.row 
  | !{marked(val)}

.another-row 
  | #{marked(val)}
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it explains why Jade behaves like that.

Comment: I have no idea how this relates to the code in question, or where a missing space figures in.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk a newline starts a new block, and interpolation doesn't work the way you'd expect it to. Although the question doesn't have this scenario, the *same* error was thrown by jade for wrong interpolation, which this answer tries to explain. If you follow the link to the github issue, you'd get a little more info on this.

Answer (score 3):

I took your code and copied into Notepad++ with View Whitespace on.

Line 28 has 4 extra spaces at the end of it (shown as dashes here):

```
input(style="width:75px;height:30px;", type="submit", value="Login")----
```

Also, line 34 has several extra spaces after "Register" as well.

Answer (score 1):

this may also be caused by using tabs instead of spaces

```
div(attr="val")[\t]text
```

or by `\t` characters at the ends of lines

Comment: In sublime text - click lower right-hand corner "spaces" menu, then "convert indentation to spaces"...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you cna have this problem if you have you something like this..

```
\t \t p    Foo
\t \t p \t Foo
```

I have had the above answer also generate this error so we're both technically right. ;)

Also, if you use vim. You can see spaces by doing,

```
:set hlsearch
/ /
```