# Jade Warning ("missing space before text") on seemingly working line of code

Tags: pug

So, playing around with Jade, and have the following simple form:

```
form(method='post')#newCustomer
    fieldset
        legend Personal
        .row
            .small-7.column
                #[label First Name #[span.muted Required] #[input(name='firstName')]]
        .row
            .small-7.column
                #[label Surname #[span.muted Required] #[input(name='surname')]]
        .row
            .small-7.column
                #[label E-Mail Address #[span.muted Required] #[input(type='email' name='email')]]
```

The HTML it produces is fine, and works as I want. The compiler complains though, giving lines akin to the following:

```
Warning: missing space before text for line 10 of jade file
```

The lines it complains about are the ones beginning with the #[label]. It's not a huge deal because, as I say, the HTML is correct, but I'd like to squash the warning if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I pasted your code on [jade-lang.com](http://jade-lang.com/) and I don't see any errors.

Comment: See [Jade - missing space before text for line x of jade file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181813/jade-missing-space-before-text-for-line-x-of-jade-file).